Preserving type parameters of a constructor when replacing the instance type
I'm coding a type-safe class system using ES5 and JSDoc.
At the most basic level, the problem boils down to adding a property to the constructor's returned instance type, while preserving the type parameters of said constructor.
Suppose we have function cls:
/**
 * @param {C} constructor
 * @template {new (...args: any) => {}} C
 * @returns {new (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) => InstanceType<C> & { addedProp: "addedProp" }}
 */
function cls(constructor) {
  // Ignore the implementation
  return;
}

One would use it like this:
var A = cls(
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {T} a
   * @template T
   */
  function A(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
);

The problem
This function
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {T} a
 * @template T
 */
function A(a) {
  this.a = a;
}

Is type of
<T>(a: T): void

But my cls function does not preserve type parameters, and the return type of cls when providing it with above function A is
new (a: unknown) => A<unknown> & {
  addedProp: "addedProp";
}

Type parameters take values of the most broad type that can extend a type parameter.
var A = cls(
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {T} a
   * @template T
   */
  function A(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
);
var a = new A("constructorProp");
a.a // unknown
// ^ should be string
a.addedProp // "addedProp"

I've tried
Intersectirng the return type with C:
/**
 * @param {C} constructor
 * @template {new (...args: any) => {}} C
 * @returns {C & { new (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) => InstanceType<C> & { addedProp: "addedProp" } }}
 */
function cls(constructor) {
  // Ignore the implementation
  return;
}

With this return type annotation, cls has two signatures.
The addedProp is effectively ignored.
var A = cls(
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {T} a
   * @template T
   */
  function A(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
);
var a = new A("constructorProp");
a.a // string
a.addedProp // Property 'addedProp' does not exist on type 'A<string>'. ts(2339)


"There is no notion of new functions in ES5" - uh, no? ES5 did have [[construct]] behaviour as well.

@Bergi What I'm specifically saying is that there is no way to create a function with a type that would be assignable to new (...args: any) => any in ES5. Let me know if I'm wrong.

@jcalz The resulting type from InstanceType<Prototype["constructor"]> is not irrelevant, as this is a part of instance's type. The error on it is irrelevant, as the resulting type is correct.
I've corrected the misspellings of constructor.
I would also love if it was plain TypeScript, it can't be though.

@jcalz Return type of cls should:

be a constructor (new (...args: any) => any) with parameters of passed constructor fn (✅);
with return type of passed constructor fn & type of passed prototype (✅);
with the type of this be return type of passed constructor fn & type of passed prototype (✅);
with the same type parameters (✅);
and type parameters should apply as expected (❌);


@jcalz second code block, from var a = new A("a");

@jcalz I've updated the question body with a more formal explanation of what I'm trying to achieve.
The playground link you provided does not meet the requirements that I provided.
Regarding the error, I can't fix it and I can't remove the code that triggers it, as this code is integral to definition of type of class instance that constructorValue is constructing.

(see prev comment) • Might I ask exactly how my code doesn't meet the requirements? It sure looks like it works as advertised to me, except that you need to annotate your types better. • Anyway it seems we're probably at an impasse, so if you don't reply I'll assume I can't be of help.

(see prev comments) • So I just spent some effort translating my suggestion from TS to JSDoc and, even though the types are exactly the same, it doesn't work. Looks like the support in ms/TS#30215 isn't kicking in and I don't know why. Maybe a TS bug, maybe my lack of JSDoc knowledge. Anyway, I think I'm stuck for now. If I find out more I'll check back, otherwise, good luck!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@jcalz I've updated the question. My assumption about the error was proven wrong. The question now represents the most basic understating of the problem.

Okay, great. Has anything relevant changed about the fact that the TS version works but the equivalent JSDoc version doesn't? Am I right in thinking that if my version worked in JSDoc that it would be acceptable for you? Or am I still missing something?
